# i am trying to put the last sentence "else : print("are you without a name?")" in a loop where it keep asking until a valid answer is given

Tags: python, loops

```
name = input("what is your name: ")


while name:

    if name.isnumeric():
        name = input("please write a valid name ")
    else:
        print(f"hello {name}")
        break
else :
    print("are you without a name?")
```

Comment: write `not name.isalpha()` instead of `name.isnumeric()`

Comment: You do not need your last `else` unless you forgot to include another `if`.

Comment: If you expect your user to provide a different name (when requires) then you need to have `input()` inside the loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly ask for the input and check if valid in the while statement, looping until a valid name has been entered. That whole clause can be this 3 simpler lines.

```
while not (name := input("what is your name: ")).isalpha():
    print("please write a valid name ")
print(f"hello {name}")
```

Output:

```
$ python script.py 
what is your name: Agent007
please write a valid name 
what is your name: 1234
please write a valid name 
what is your name: Bond
hello Bond
```